# Two divisible lists

Tags: python

I need this function to return `True` if all of the numbers of `list_1` can be divisible by at least one number in `list_2`. I tried to use the all function for this like :

```py
for num1 in list_1: 
    if all(num1 % num2 == 0 for num2 in list_2)
    return True
```

The problem with my solution is that it checks if ALL the numbers in `list_1` can be divisible by ALL the numbers in `list_2`, and that is not what I require.

I'm wondering if there is a way to do it such that all the numbers of `list_1` have atleast one factor in `list_2`? An example would be:

List_1 = [15, 10, 4, 8, 12]
List_2 = [2, 5, 3]
output True

List_1 = [15, 10, 7, 8, 12]
List_2 = [2, 5, 3]
output False

It is False in the 2nd situation as 7 can't be divided by any of the numbers in `list_2`.

Comment: Hey, do you wanna know if one number in list2 is a factor of all the numbers in list1?

Comment: Please edit to say "if ALL the numbers in list 1 can be divisible by ANY" instead of "if ALL the numbers in list 1 can be divisible by ALL".

Comment: Hey, I have made an edit, that improves this question. Accept it if it makes sense

Answer (score 4):

You can combine `all` and `any` in a comprehension:

```py
>>> l1=[8,10,20]
>>> l2=[2,3]
>>> any(all(n1%n2==0 for n1 in l1) for n2 in l2)
True
```

If you want to check any number in list1 should be divisible by at least one number in list 2, you can restructure above statement as follows:

```py
>>> l1,l2=[15, 10, 4, 8, 12],[2, 5, 3]
>>> all(any(n1%n2 for n2 in l2) for n1 in l1)
True
```

Comment: Good point about division by 0, but OP asked for a way to test if *all* numbers in one list are divisible by *all* numbers in a second list. This checks if all numbers in the first list are divisible by *any* in the second.

Comment: unfortunately this still dosent work for me :(

if l1 is [15, 10, 4, 8, 12] and l2 is [2, 5, 3], it should return True but it is currently returning False

Comment: @thisisrandy I know that but what if the 2nd list itself contains a zero?

Comment: @ThePyGuy Wouldn't you already fail if `n2` were at any point `0`?

Comment: @thisisrandy I just removed zero division case altogether assuming the 2nd list is not going to contain the zero based on sample data provided by OP

Comment: @RajKrish `[15, 10, 4, 8, 12] and [2, 5, 3],` should result `False` based on the question you've asked.

Comment: @thisisrandy i am indeed asking for a way to check if ALL the numbers in the first list are divisible by ANY numbers in the second list, but ThePyguys's solution still dosent work

Comment: @ThePyGuy each of the numbers in the list are divisible by either 2, 5 or 3, so it should return True

Comment: @RajKrish Then you should probably restate your question saying that any of the number in list 1 is divisible by at least 1 number in list 2

Comment: @RajKrish You explicitly say "check if ALL the numbers in list 1 can be divisible by ALL the numbers in list2." If you meant *all* by *any*, please modify your question accordingly. ThePyGuy's solution is correct for the latter case.

Comment: @RajKrish Okay look at the updated answer, it has both the cases. Case 1: as mentioned in the question all number in list1 is divisible by any number in list2, Case 2: All number in list 1 is divisible by at least one number in list 2

Comment: Yo it works!!!!! Thank you so much for the help, and it looks incredibly clean as well

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there. [List comprehensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension) can contain an arbitrary number of variables, in which case all combinations of them will be considered. You can simply say

```py
return all(l1_elm % l2_elm == 0 for l1_elm in List1 for l2_elm in List2)
```

This is equivalent to

```py
for l1_elm in List1:
    for l2_elm is List2:
        # if this doesn't evaluate to 0
        if l1_elm % l2_elm:
            return False
return True
```

By the way, it's idiomatic in python to use [snake_case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) for variables and [PascalCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) for classes, so your `List1` and `List2` should ideally be written as `list_1` (or just `list1`) and `list_2`, respectively.

@ThePyGuy also makes a good point. The [modulo operator](https://realpython.com/python-modulo-operator/) fails if the second argument is `0` with `ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero`. If you expect that `List2` might contain a `0` value, you should also check for that before attempting to divide, i.e. modify the condition to `if l2_elm == 0 or l1_elm % l2_elm`.

EDIT: OP has indicated that they actually meant check if *all* values in `List1` are divisible by *any* values in `List2`. For that case, the following code is appropriate

```py
return any(all(l1_elm % l2_elm == 0 for l1_elm in List1) for l2_elm in List2)
```

Which is exactly @ThePyGuy's original answer. This is equivalent to

```py
for l2_elm in List2:
    all_divisible = True
    for l1_elm in List1:
        if l1_elm % l2_elm:
            all_divisible = False
            # this l2_elm didn't work. no need to check further List1
            # values for divisibility
            break
    # this particular l2_elm divided everything successfully, so
    # return True
    if all_divisible:
        return True
# nothing worked, so fail
return False
```

Comment: Hey, just looking at this code and I am wondering what the return true in the end does? In the first part before the edit

Comment: @PythonProgrammer that last statement (`return True`) only executes if the loop has completed without itself returning a value. Recall that all of this is to be done inside of a function.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that this was to be done in a function. It makes sense then, if the loop returns a value, the ```return True``` become obsolete

Comment: @Raj Krish, I feel this solution explains it better and should be accepted.